# how to run the django kronos automatically

Tags: python, django

I want to use django Kronos to compare 'end_date' of Member model and today every 1.a.m.

So, I installed 'django-Kronos' and wrote 'Kronos' in installed app.

I made the file in my root of the project.

```
from staff.models import Member
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import kronos
import random

@kronos.register('1 * * * *')
def the_task():
    today = datetime.date.today() 
    Member.objects.filter(end_date__lte=today).update(Membership_status=0)
```

To test, I wrote `python manage.py runtask the_task`
But, `CommandError: Task 'the_task' not found` happens.

How I run the cron.py automatically??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't particularly tied to using kronos, you could instead set it up as a management command, so that you can run it from the terminal like: `$ python manage.py the_task`.

From there you can run it as a cronjob from your OS, or many hosting companies offer scheduled tasks that could be used to run something like this.

To set up a management command, in one of your app directories, create the following directory structure: management/commands/

inside the commands directory create a python file called: `the_task.py` and edit it to contain the following code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from staff.models import Member
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

class Command(BaseCommand):

    args = ''

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        today = datetime.date.today() 
        Member.objects.filter(end_date__lte=today).update(Membership_status=0)
```

I've found doing it like this is much simpler, doesn't require libraries apart from standard django, and is easily testable since you can run it from the terminal as well.

Comment: If one of my app names is 'management',  I should make management/management/commands directory path, right? How I make the code run automatic every 1.a.m?

Comment: Correct. Running the code automatically at 1am depends on what OS you are testing on, and then later, what OS your project is deployed to. On Unix based systems you can use 'cron', on Windows, you use 'at'. What OS are you developing/deploying on?

Comment: I'm using Windows.  Could you tell me more detail about using 'at'??

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never developed on Windows before, so I'm not too familiar with the 'at' command. Here is the documentation for the command though: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks

Sorry I can't be more helpful. I hope that's enough to get you started.

Comment: It's enough :) Thank you so much your help!!

Comment: Ahh I'm using Windows for local, but I'm using AWS (Ubuntu instance) for the server. Then, should I write differently with 'at'?

Comment: Okay, the correct way to do this is to get [VirutalBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), then run the same version Ubuntu that AWS uses from your Windows machine and develop your site on that. It would be easier to deploy, and you would be able write and test cronjobs locally before you wrote them on AWS. This is quite involved though, and can take some time to set up if you've never done it before.

Comment: An easier (but far less robust) way would be to write the management command from my answer, test it locally, then add it to a cronjob on the AWS server when you deploy the site. However, it comes with some downsides: You will have to get it running, and debug it on your on your server, which can be especially frustrating if you are doing something for the first time

There is not much point in writing an 'at' command since you will have to replace it with a cronjob once you deploy the site.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the django-kronos README file, "Kronos collects tasks from cron modules in your project root and each of your applications". I think you missed the point here which states, cron tasks should be in a cron.py file defined in your project root or app directory. that is why the kronos couldn't find the task.